# VLC Player: effects and filters not working with mp4 videos

Tags: vlc-media-player

There is not much I can say about it. All of the sudden, effects stopped working in VLC with mp4 videos. They do work with webm and mov.

My OS is Ubuntu 16. Version of VLC is 2.2.2

Anyone experiences the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried different version?
I have no issue on effects ubuntu 16.04 vlc 2.2.2 Weatherwax I have it running well.
SO can you please post details of video and effect you were trying. best will be if you post/ point to exact video or very small part of video so that it can be reproduce.

To get detailed info about video file try this tool called mediainfo with this switch --fullscan so that we can figure out.

```
mediainfo --fullscan video.mp4
```

feel free to remove some private info.